# How to increase the value of the field nid in the node table in database?

Tags: nodes, database

I'm using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import nodes from another system. This system uses very long number for its node id, like: **17675272378**. As you can see this number has 11 digits. The problem is that Drupal only allows a nid value up to 10 digits, then the import just fails.

I thought of changing the **length** value for **nid** for the **node** table directly in the database. But it is not that simple there are a **lot** of other tables which has this field like: the **entity_id** field for the **field_data_body** table.

Maybe I can get to change the values in the database if I export the table and then find and replace the value '10' for '15' and then after I replace the database which the new one. But my question is: will I get other problems if I do this?

How can I sort this out?

Here are my captures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I thing "feeds" tag is irrelevant here. the real problem does not depend on the way data was imported. Feeds, Backup And Migrate, CSV Import etc would all act exactly the same way.

Comment: @chefnelone if you don't need that id as Drupal nid, you can create a number field(unique) for that and import with auto generate NID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing the import to use the ID of the other system will break the sequential nature of the drupal nid.  You should add a textfield on the receiving site to hold the old site id and let drupal assign new ones.

Comment: I agree that and I highly recommend not to change this field , nodes are usually joint to other modules table using nid so if you change that there will be some problems

Comment: I agree, I will change the value just before feeds import them.

Answer (score 2):

You must alter your table to change your data type from `INT` to `BIGINT` because your number `17675272378` is not suported by the `INT` data type:

```
ALTER TABLE `node` CHANGE `nid` `nid` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `field_data_body` CHANGE `entity_id` `entity_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

> INT - A normal-sized integer that can be signed or unsigned. If
>   signed, the allowable range is from -2147483648 to 2147483647. If
>   unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 4294967295. You can specify
>   a width of up to 11 digits.
>
> BIGINT - A large integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed,
>   the allowable range is from -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 18446744073709551615. You can specify a width of up to 20 digits.

For more details, refer to [MySQL Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm).